# Add new row's to div generated table using CSS, ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am sorry for this question. I am working on a option to generated a table using div tags, this works fine. I am trying to make the user add or remove a row using jQuery. My problem is that the added row is not populating all the columns. The entire row is added in the columns Header1. I have tried everything to get this to be fixed but nothing works, you guys are my last hope that is why i posted my question here.

I have tried to make a workable snipchat, the add new row is not working here, it is in my browser..

```js
$('#addrow').click(function(){
    var length = $('.sl').length;
    var i   = parseInt(length)+parseInt(1);
    var newrow = $('#next').append('<div class="divTableRow"><div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control sl" name="slno[]" value="'+i+'" readonly=""></div><div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="acc_name'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Account Name" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+"></div><div class="divTableCell"><select name="rang[]" id="rang_acc'+i+'" style="width:170px !important;font-weight: normal !important;" class="form-control"><option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option><option value="Low Life">Low Life</option><option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option><option value="Hitman">Hitman</option><option value="Assassin">Assassin</option><option value="Local Boss">Local Boss</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Godfather">Godfather</option></select></div><div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_no[]" id="pn'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Phone No"></div><div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="age'+i+'" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></div><div class="divTableCell"><input type="date" id="dob'+i+'" name="date_of_birth[]" class="form-control"/></div><div class="divTableCell"><input type="button" class="btnRemove btn-danger" value="Remove"/></div></div>');
    
});
    
// Removing event here
$('body').on('click','.btnRemove',function() {
   $(this).closest('div').remove()
});
```

```css
div.blueTable {
    border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell, .divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
    background: #D0E4F5;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading {
    background: #1C6EA4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle {
    font-size: 11px;
}
.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
    text-align: right;
}
.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1C6EA4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.blueTable.outerTableFooter {
    border-top: none;
}
.blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
    padding: 3px 5px; 
}
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableFoot { display: table-footer-group;}
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="divTable blueTable">
        <div class="divTableHeading">
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableHead">head1</div>
                <div class="divTableHead">head2</div>
                <div class="divTableHead">head3</div>
                <div class="divTableHead">head4</div>
                <div class="divTableHead">head5</div>
                <div class="divTableHead">head6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableBody">
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control sl" name="slno[]" id="slno" value="1" readonly="">
                </div>
                <div class="divTableCell">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="acc_name" placeholder="Enter Account Name" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+">
                </div>
                <div class="divTableCell"> 
                    <select name="rang[]" id="rang_acc" style="width:120px !important;font-weight: normal !important;" class="form-control sl">  
                        <option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option>   
                        <option value="Low Life">Low Life</option>
                        <option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option> 
                        <option value="Hitman">Hitman</option>
                        <option value="Assassin">Assassin</option> 
                        <option value="Local Boss">Local Boss</option> 
                        <option value="Boss">Boss</option> 
                        <option value="Godfather">Godfather</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
               <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_no[]" id="pn" placeholder="Enter Phone No"></div>
               <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></div>
               <div class="divTableCell"><input type="date" id="dob" name="date_of_birth[]" class="form-control"/></div>
            </div>
            <div id="next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add New Row</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, change `$('#next')` to `$('.divTableBody')` so the new row will get appended inside `divTableBody` .Working fiddle check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rhzkewb2/)

Comment: Thank you that works for the adding new rows !. The remove row wont work now, what change should be made there?

Comment: You can use `$(this).closest('div.divTableRow').remove()` try it let me if that works or not .

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks. Can i somehow accept this as the right answer?

Comment: One answer has already been given you can accept that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are adding long HTML strings, use backticks (`) for interpolation - this allows you to create multi-line strings
2. I suggest that you put (especially long) HTML strings outside of your click handler. Much cleaner, easier to track
3. You appended the whole HTML string to `#next` instead of your table body container `divTableBody`
4. Also, there are one fewer columns than cells you create
5. Added `.parent()` to your `remove` function - now it works

```js
const tableRow = (i) => {
  return `
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="text" class="form-control sl" name="slno[]" value="${ i }" readonly="">
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="acc_name${ i }" placeholder="Enter Account Name" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+">
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <select name="rang[]" id="rang_acc${ i }" style="width:170px !important;font-weight: normal !important;" class="form-control">
          <option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option>
          <option value="Low Life">Low Life</option>
          <option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option>
          <option value="Hitman">Hitman</option>
          <option value="Assassin">Assassin</option>
          <option value="Local Boss">Local Boss</option>
          <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
          <option value="Godfather">Godfather</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_no[]" id="pn${ i }" placeholder="Enter Phone No">
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age${ i }" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age">
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="date" id="dob${ i }" name="date_of_birth[]" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <input type="button" class="btnRemove btn-danger" value="Remove"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

$('#addrow').click(function() {
  var length = $('.sl').length;
  var i = parseInt(length) + parseInt(1);
  var newrow = $('.divTableBody').append(tableRow(i));
});

// Removing event here
$('body').on('click', '.btnRemove', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').parent().remove()
});
```

```css
div.blueTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell,
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: #D0E4F5;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
  text-align: right;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1C6EA4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter {
  border-top: none;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}


/* DivTable.com */

.divTable {
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
}

.divTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableFoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="divTable blueTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableHead">head1</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head2</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head3</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head4</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head5</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head6</div>
        <div class="divTableHead">head7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control sl" name="slno[]" id="slno" value="1" readonly=""></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="acc_name" placeholder="Enter Account Name" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell">
          <select name="rang[]" id="rang_acc" style="width:120px !important;font-weight: normal !important;" class="form-control sl">
            <option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option>
            <option value="Low Life">Low Life</option>
            <option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option>
            <option value="Hitman">Hitman</option>
            <option value="Assassin">Assassin</option>
            <option value="Local Boss">Local Boss</option>
            <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
            <option value="Godfather">Godfather</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_no[]" id="pn" placeholder="Enter Phone No"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><input type="date" id="dob" name="date_of_birth[]" class="form-control" /></div>
      </div>
      <div id="next"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add New Row</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Submit</button>
</form>
```